# Excel: How to (temporarily) disable prompt when open file from hyperlink?

Tags: microsoft-excel, security, microsoft-office

is there a way how to (temporarily) disable warnings when I try to open file by clicking hyperlink in Excel?

[image]

I tried to add folder (and subfolders) to [`Trusted location`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4). (Obviously) doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File**- **Options**- **Trust Center**- **Trust Center Settings...**- **Protected View**- ***Uncheck*** all options.

Go to **File**- **Options**- **Trust Center**- **Trust Center Settings...**- **File Block Settings**- ***Uncheck*** all options.

You may also check **External content** and **Message bar** also in Trust Center.

Comment: Prompt is still shown. But not for all files. Files (what I've tried so far) `*.jpg`, `*.pdf`, `*.xls`, `*.xlsx` are opened without the prompt. But for other (not so common extensions) is prompt stil shown (like `*.tif` which is set to open with Windows default viewer). Seems like there is extension whitelist...